# How do I construct a crosswalk table with multiple crosswalks with the ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I wanna present my crosswalk results for 5 different crosswalks in a combined table with the ggplot2 package.

I've created a data.frame with all results that need to be displayed:

```
crosswalk <- data.frame(subset(fsdiscDET,, (1:2)),(subset(fsdiscDIS,, 2)), 
(subset(fsdiscANT,, 2)), (subset(fsdiscPSY,, 2)),(subset(fsdiscANPICD,, 2)), 
(subset(fsdiscANPID5,,2)))

#Define Column names for the data frame named "crosswalk
colnames(crosswalk) <- c("SumScore", "ThetaDET", "ThetaDIS","ThetaANT", "ThetaPSY", 
"ThetaANPiCD", "ThetaPID5BF+M")
```

The table is constructed like this:

```
 SumScores    ThetaDET    ThetaDIS     ThetaANT   ThetaPSY   ThetaANPiCD  ThetaPID5BF+M

0               -2           ...          ....

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8
```

Unfortunately, I can't show my real results but the table is filled with scores, that should be displayed as a crosswalk from the sum scores, so here is some example data: (first row)

```
   > dput(head(crosswalk, 1))
   structure(list(SumScore = 0L, ThetaDET = -0.880871248855981, 
      ThetaDIS = -0.594351208632866, ThetaANT = -0.463495518249115, 
    ThetaPSY = -0.471562212797643, ThetaANPiCD = 
    -0.850865132469677, 
   `ThetaPID5BF+M` = -0.91391979254119), row.names = 0L, class = 
    "data.frame")
```

Here is an example of what I want to create: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fxbV.png)

In my case, the different "columns" of the example would be the sum scores (0 to 8)  of the table I have created above. The crosswalk would than be to place the sum scores on the y-axis (Theta), where the corresponding Theta score would be. So the different columns like ThetaDET and ThetaDIS are all filled with values from -3 to 4 and should be represented at the left y-axis of the graphic.

Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share your example data in a way that people can load directly. Can you run `dput(crosswalk)` or `dput(head(crosswalk, N))` where N is enough rows to demonstrate your situation, and paste the output into the body of your question?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see what the issue is.  You'll need to tell us the packages you are using and provide some example data that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I added the first row, which I think is enough to reproduce it, since there is a value for every single crosswalk I wanna do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with the `mtcars` dataset. We can reshape long, then scale within each variable, and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(scaled = as.numeric(scale(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, scaled, label = value, color = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = "-", size = 7) +
  geom_text(hjust = -0.5, size = 2, alpha = 0.7, check_overlap =TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top", name = NULL) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot! but now, the values that are in the crosswalk data.frame in column 2-6 are in the different columns of the graphik whereas, I need them to be scored on the scaled axis in your example and the corresponding sum scores (column 1 of the crosswalk dataframe) in the different columns of the graphic.. It seems like I do not understand your example code well enough to change that

Comment: Can you add to your question to explain what you are looking for? In the example above, each variable has a value as well as a scaled t-score value. The y axis shows the t-score and the text shows the underlying value.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough: The problem is, that with your code, I get the columns of my example (ThetaDET - ThetaANPID5BF+M) as the different columsn of the graphic, but instead I need the assiciated sum score in the different columns.. also these sum scores need to be placed, so that the y value is the associated Thetascore of them.. so my y axis would be scaled from -4 to 4 so that every value of the columns "ThetaDET"-"ThetaANPID5BF+" can be scored on it

Comment: "instead I need the associated sum score in the different columns" -- sorry I don't know what this means. Perhaps you can show an example calculation that goes from data to expected result?

Comment: in my table that i have created above, the row names are the assiciated sumscores. Underneath, i added the first row of my real table, which depicts the associated theta scores (ThetaDET - ThetaANPID5BF). it reads like this: for a sum score of 0 , the estimated ThetaDET is -0.880871248855981, the estimated ThetaDIS is -0.594351208632866 and so forth. The crosswalk table needs to have the sum scores ( from 0 to 8) in every "column". (In your example this would be "am" "carb", "cyl", ... ) and the theta scores on the y-axis ( in your example, thats "scaled" from -2 to 3

Comment: I finally found the right way, thank you for your example code!!